# How can add all files in public directory to the build directory with parcel-bundler

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, devops, parceljs

I use parcel-bundler on a react app. But I realized I need to redirect all files index.html using HTTP files but when I add a .htaccess file to my public directory. It's not added to the dist folder after building the project.

How can I achieve this without adding files manually after building?

Comment: the given answer does not work. did u find the answer ?

Comment: What didn't work about it? it just copies the file. If you're on windows you need to use the copy command rather than cp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set up a custom copy script in your package.json that you can use in your build script or wherever you need :)

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build && npm run copy",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "copy": "cp public/.htaccess dist"
  },
```

Note: Windows users will need to use the `copy` command rather than `cp`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `parcel-plugin-static-files-copy`. On build it automatically copies everything in the `static` to `dist`.

You could place your `.htaccess` there and done.